# Rails, How to deliver dynamic email depending on user status after session expiration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, sendgrid, email-delivery, sendgrid-rails

So I have a website similar to an e-commerce site. I want to send out an email to the user after session expiry(preferably 30min after expiry), with dynamic content - with respect to their status, i.e. if they have items in their cart, if they haven't paid, or if the payment was successful.

So there are three questions here?

- What are different ways to achieve this?
- Is it possible to run a section of code after 30min of session expiration?
- Is it possible to put an if-else statement to the mail delivery depending on the user status?

Currently, I'm using Rails 5.0.0, and sendgrid to send emails. Sendgrid has codes like Mail.deliver_after(30 mins). But I can't seem to put an if else condition to make the content of the email dynamic. Also, I want to send the email after 30 mins after session expiry.

Comment: When does user session expire? After exact period of time or after inactivate?

Comment: I haven't worked with session expiry. It's whatever the default is. To my knowledge, it expires on browser close. Should I set the time manually?

Comment: You need a way to detect when user session is expired so that you know when to end email. If set time provide that information you can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are different ways to achieve this?

```
- Using background job. Create asynchronous jobs with run time and priority.
```

Is it possible to run a section of code after 30min of session expiration?

```
- Use delayed_job gem or use some other background job gems. Using asynchronously
```

Is it possible to put an if-else statement to the mail delivery depending on the user status?

```
 - Called mail delivery using background job so you can send mail whenever you want.
```

Comment: Thank you! I set up sidekiq with a redis database.